# How can I make this variable available in my php endpoints?

Tags: php

I'm working on a legacy php website and embedding a React app. I need to get the customer id from an existing class in the website. I'm able to require the file and access the variable in index.php, but in my endpoints I'm not able to require it. When I do, I get a status 500. I've tried using $_SESSION, but in my endpoint it's just an empty array. I'm pretty new with php and I'm not sure what else to do.

My project structure is as such:

project-directory/

- index.php
- api/endpoint.php

How do I get a variable from index.php to endpoint.php?

index.php

```
<?php

header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", "On");

require_once $_SERVER["HTTP_ROOT_PATH"] . "/admin/include/shop.php";

global $BuyNow;

readfile(__DIR__ . "/client/build/index.html");
```

$BuyNow is the variable in question

Comment: If you get a 500 error, check the php error log file to find out the exact error message

Answer (score 0):

You Can Just require The Index.php File From the Api/Endpoint.php file ?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).